# Python get JSON Response from XHR Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying for some time to build a get request using requests and other python tools, which should actually return a JSON.

To get closer to the topic, I first try to reproduce the whole thing in the browser. Thereby I already come to limits.

It's about this URL:
https://unverpackt-verband.de/map

When I look at the network analysis in Firefox, I see the desired json under Response. But the Request section is empty.[image]

Now I would appreciate help on how to find/build a suitable request to get and process this JSON in an automated way using python.

---

EDIT what has been tried so far:

---

requests.get("https://api.unverpacktverband.de/map").json()
Outcome: "TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects." Error

Comment: what is wrong with `my_json_response = requests.get("https://api.unverpacktverband.de/map").json()` ? looks like a text book example case for `requests` module.

Comment: I get a "TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects." error.

Comment: Yeah, that page is broken. I get the same redirect loop in python-requests, curl and firefox. How did you manage to get a Status 200 OK response in your browser?

Comment: I got the 200 OK response after I cleared the cache again. The first time the response seems to be 200 and when I repeat it I get a 304 and it pulls the data from the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking for the following?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


headers = {'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://api.unverpackt-verband.de/map'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

df = pd.json_normalize(r.json())
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    id  type    lat lng
0   1985    storeNoMember   47.558307   9.709220
1   1984    plannedMember   48.941530   8.405472
2   1983    storeMember 49.999355   8.711121
3   1982    mobilePlannedMember 51.838272   6.614867
4   1981    plannedMember   52.841810   7.519561
... ... ... ... ...
631 850 storeNoMember   50.713607   7.044930
632 849 storeNoMember   51.486631   7.214458
633 847 storeMember 49.898628   10.896140
634 846 storeMember 49.840614   7.861260
635 845 storeNoMember   52.201666   8.788376
636 rows × 4 columns
```